# Store parent cell id in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cell

I have a table which will output the id of the parent cell when it is clicked. How could I change this so it outputs more than one clicked cell. For example, right now if I click cell id '1' it will output 1. If I click cell '2' it will output 2 and so on. How can I make it so that it outputs '1,2,3' given that I've clicked on cell 1, 2 and 3. 
HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='test' id='1'><img src='images/Dog.gif'/></td>
        <td class='test' id='2'><img src='images/Cat.gif'/></td>
        <td class='test' id='3'><img src='images/Mouse.gif'/></td>
        <td class='test' id='4'><img src='images/Human.gif'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id='output'></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('td.test').click(function() { 
        $('#output').text(this.id);
    });
});
```

Also, is there a way that if I clicked back on say, cell 2. it would remove '2' from the list.

Comment: And if I click 1-2-1 will it output 1,2,1 or 1,2?

Comment: if you click 1, 2, 1 it will only show 2. As you've removed the 1 by re-clicking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to keep track of clicked items:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var clicked = [];
    $('td.test').click(function() {
        var found = clicked.indexOf(this.id);

        // Remove
        if(found !== -1) {
            clicked.splice(found, 1);

        // Add
        } else {
            clicked.push(this.id);
        }
        $('#output').text(clicked.join(','));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mx2kj/

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = "";

$(".test").on("click", function () {

    $(this).data("selected", !$(this).data("selected"));

    var ids = $(".test").filter(function () {
       return $(this).data("selected") === true; 
    }).map(function () {
       return this.id; 
    }).get().join(",");

    alert(ids);

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fY5tj/1

Comment: how could I use this in the div? although this is what i was looking for so thanks

Comment: Simply `$("#output").text(ids);` where the alert is.

Answer (score 0):

You can append your clicked item id in your output div like this :

```
$('td.test').click(function() { 
 var currentText = $("#output").text();
 $("#output").text(currentText+this.id);
});
```